# Refactoring a Controller in symfony to adapt to hexagonal architecture

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, frameworks, symfony

I have create a controller that creates a Owner record into database. Everything was done on the CreateOwnerController like this and working properly:

```
class CreateOwnerController extends Controller
{
     public function executeAction(Request $request)
     { 
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $owner = new Owner($request->request->get("name"));
       $em->persist($owner);
       $em->flush();

    return new Response('Added',200);
}
```

}

Now,In order to refactor that I have created an interface that defines the OwnerRepository:

```
interface OwnerRepositoryInterface {
    public function save(Owner $owner);
}
```

And a OwnerRepository that implements this interface:

```
class OwnerRepository extends EntityRepository implements OwnerRepositoryInterface {
    public function save(Owner $owner) {
        $this->_em->persist($owner);
        $this->_em->flush();
    }
}
```

Then I have Created for the application layer a CreateOwnerUseCase Class that receives a OwnerRepository and executes a method to save in into OwnerRepository:

```
class CreateOwnerUseCase {
    private $ownerRepository;
    public function __construct(OwnerRepositoryInterface $ownerRepository) {
        $this->ownerRepository = $ownerRepository;
    }

    public function execute(string $ownerName) {
        $owner = new Owner($ownerName);
        $this->ownerRepository->save($owner);
    }
}
```

Ok, i'm spliting the initial Controller intro layer Domain / Aplication / Framework layers.

On the `CreateOwnerController` now i have instantiated that Use Case and passed as parameter the `OwnerRepository` like this:

```
class CreateOwnerController extends Controller {
    public function executeAction(Request $request) { 
        $createOwnerUseCase = new CreateOwnerUseCase(new OwnerRepository());
        $createOwnerUseCase->execute($request->request->get("name"));
        return new Response('Added',200);
    }

}
```

But it fails when Make the request to create new Owner:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct(), called in /ansible/phpexercises/Frameworks/mpweb-frameworks-symfony/src/MyApp/Bundle/AppBundle/Controller/CreateOwnerController.php

It happens on `OwnerRepository` passed as parameter. It wants an `$em` and Mapped Class... What is the meaning of this mapped Class? How solve this error?

Comment: Since OwnerRepository is actually a Doctrine EntityRepository you can only create it using EntityManager::getRepository.  Search around a bit for examples.  You best bet with this sort of approach would be to create a service for owner repository and pretty much avoid the use of the php new operator.

Comment: Looks like you have an syntax error in your code-example in `CreateOwnerController` you are using `return` inside the class but not in a method.

Comment: @Roman Sure, I missed when copy/paste. Now it's equal .

Comment: @Cerad it means that I would have to pass to CreateOwnerUseCase($em-> getRepository(Owner))? Or get repository inside the CreateOwnerUseCase class? Regards

Comment: No.  If you are going to go through all the effort of making all these classes then you need to see how Symfony implements dependency injection: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html as well as getting up to speed on Doctrine 2.

Comment: How does your service registration in config look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is for **Symfony 3.3+/4+**.

You need to register your repository as a service. Instead of extending it 3rd party code, you should use composition over inheritance.

```
final class OwnerRepository implements OwnerRepositoryInterface
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function save(Owner $owner) 
    {
        $this->entityManager->persist($owner);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

And register it as a service:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    App\Repository\:
        # for location app/Repository
        resource: ../Repository
```

You might need to tune paths a bit, to make that work.

To get more extended answer, see [How to use Repository with Doctrine as Service in Symfony](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony/)